# Could NOT find CURL (missing: CURL_LIBRARY CURL_INCLUDE_DIR) on CMake

Tags: curl, cmake

I'm trying to use api.ai C++ library on Windows 7.
(https://github.com/api-ai/libapiai)
But i can not configuring that files..

I installed CMake and MinGW.

in build directory 
-> cmake .. -G "MinGW Makefiles" 
-> Error !!

===>>> error is below <<<

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.4/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148 (message):
  Could NOT find CURL (missing: CURL_LIBRARY CURL_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.4/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:388 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.4/Modules/FindCURL.cmake:61 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:45 (find_package)
```

I don't know how can I solve.
what is curl_library? 
I can use that on Windows 7? not linux/unix etc..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just search the internet for curl! It's a library to transfer data with an URL syntax. You can download binaries from it's [download page](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html) or download the source code and compile it locally. If you use NuGet, you can grab [their package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/curl/) instead.

If it is installed, delete your CMakeCache.txt file and re-run CMake. If you don't want to install it, pass `-DCURL_LIBRARY=<curl_lib_path> -DCURL_INCLUDE_DIR=<curl_include_path` to your CMake call.

Comment: Thank you so much. I built that cURL with VS2012 and I got libcurl.dll, libcurl.lib, and several header files in include folder. But I don't know correct PATH... I still have same error. Where should i do to copy that library files? Is it Cmake directory or MinGW directory or api.ai directory? I really appreciate your teaching.

Comment: I worked! Thank you. Can i have any further questions? I still have some error.

Comment: I commanded 'make install', however cmd returned just _Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601] Copyright ... _. And I can not run the INSTALL because there only exist Makefile, CTestTestfile.cmake, cmake_install.cmake, and directories... help me. really thank you.

Comment: "Just search the internet" should not be considered the correct answer. Josh's or Muhammad Mubashir's answer should be the correct one

Comment: As far as I can tell, my answer is the only one addressing "what is curl_library?".

Answer (score 43):

Try installing curl with the dev libraries:

`sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt install curl && sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev`

Comment: This is the correct answer.  You need the curl development package to get the curl headers and libraries you need.

Comment: @Jabberwock That's the correct answer for Linux, not for Mac OS or Windows. The question is clearly targeting Windows.

Answer (score 27):

If you are using Ubuntu:
**sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev**

If you are using Centos:
**sudo yum install libcurl-devel**

Answer (score 13):

My issue was fixed by,(installed `libssl-dev` addtionally to @Josh answer)

```
sudo apt-get install curl
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

[CMAKE_USE_SYSTEM_CURL is ON but a curl is not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56941778/cmake-use-system-curl-is-on-but-a-curl-is-not-found)

Answer (score 1):

In fedora, install libcurl-devel

`sudo dnf install libcurl-devel`