# Cmake error "missing: CURL_LIBRARY CURL_INCLUDE_DIR" on Windows 10

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, curl, cmake

I am trying to build the Amazon IoT Device SDK from here
https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-cpp/blob/master/Platform.md

I followed the instructions by installing all the required tools including CMake and OpenSSL. I try to build the SDK with CMake but I get this error:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:146 (message):
  Could NOT find CURL (missing: CURL_LIBRARY CURL_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):

  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:393 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindCURL.cmake:143 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  tests/unit/CMakeLists.txt:59 (find_package)
```

I don't understand why I am getting this error because I have the CURL Library installed from this link:
https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/

I also tried the solution from this question but had no luck 
[Could NOT find CURL (missing: CURL_LIBRARY CURL_INCLUDE_DIR) on CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34914944/could-not-find-curl-missing-curl-library-curl-include-dir-on-cmake)

Comment: There is no standard location to install libraries on windows so sometimes you need to tell `CMake` where to look.

Comment: ***I also tried the solution from this question but had no luck*** That should have worked. You will need to show your steps and results of trying for someone to help.

Comment: That step from that solution was installing the CURL Library exe file directly from the website

Comment: Does not mean `CMake` will look there.